# C# / WPF Object animated appearance

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I wrote a little Application to manage the working time.

When my Mouse enters the Window an an Option to see more information appears (Green field in Picture) [Application on Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYoBA.png)
On click on the green field an Ellipse should appear slowly from bottom to the top (Red field in Picture)[Application expand information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvTyq.png)
At the moment i just appears instantly.
Heres my Code:

```
 private void addEvents()
    {
       [...]
        gridExpandInfo.MouseUp += GridExpandInfo_Click;
        gridExpandInfo.MouseDown += GridExpandInfo_Click;

        btnHideInfoPanel.Click += BtnHideInfoPanel_Click;
    }

    private void BtnHideInfoPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        gridInformationPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void GridExpandInfo_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        gridInformationPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found smth thats animate the Appearance of my Grid.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="infoIn">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="gridInformationPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="248">

        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="infoOut">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetName="gridInformationPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="248" To="0">

        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

Starting the animation is the .cs file:

```
   private void BtnHideInfoPanel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb = FindResource("infoOut") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(informationPanel);
        sb.Completed += Sb_Completed;

    }

    private void Sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void GridExpandInfo_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        gridInformationPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        gridExpandInfo.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        Storyboard sb = FindResource("infoIn") as Storyboard;
        sb.Begin(informationPanel);

    }
```

But somehow my gridExpandInfo will also disappear. 
Anybody knows how to change the Animation to start building the grid at its endpoint up to its startpoint?

```
 <Grid x:Name="gridInformationPanel" Width="248" Height="248" Margin="26">
        <Ellipse x:Name="informationPanel"  Fill="#FFFF0505" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2">
            <Ellipse.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,25,248,248"/>
            </Ellipse.Clip>

        </Ellipse>
        <Button x:Name="btnHideInfoPanel" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="114,24,114,204" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"  >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="UserControls/Images/Button-Eject-icon-down.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```